# MediaWiki: Global default '' is invalid for field editfont

Tags: debugging, mediawiki

Anyone see and know what this error means and/or how to fix it?  I place it in a google search and it doesn't appear to be something that anyone normally has an issue with:

```
Global default '' is invalid for field editfont
Backtrace:
#0 /srv/http/SupportWiki/includes/Preferences.php(1152): Preferences::getPreferences(Object(User))
#1 /srv/http/SupportWiki/includes/specials/SpecialPreferences.php(43): Preferences::getFormObject(Object(User))
#2 /srv/http/SupportWiki/includes/SpecialPage.php(559): SpecialPreferences->execute(NULL)
#3 /srv/http/SupportWiki/includes/Wiki.php(254): SpecialPage::executePath(Object(Title))
#4 /srv/http/SupportWiki/includes/Wiki.php(64): MediaWiki->handleSpecialCases(Object(Title), Object(OutputPage), Object(WebRequest))
#5 /srv/http/SupportWiki/index.php(117): MediaWiki->performRequestForTitle(Object(Title), NULL, Object(OutputPage), Object(User), Object(WebRequest))
#6 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running MediaWiki 1.16.0.  I upgraded to MediaWiki 1.16.2 and this resolved the issue.

Comment: For what it's worth, wasn't able to find the changelog for 1.16.x minor upgrades.  From the author site, it appears they want you to diff the patch file to see what has changed.